# How to use Hashset for non-string objects in java

Tags: java

Lets say I have created a class called Time whose constructor takes 3 params. hour, mins and secs.
Now, I create an object `t1 = new Time(10, 10, 10);` and then another object `t2 = new Time(10, 10, 10)`

now I use them in hashset.

```
hashset.add(t1);
hashset.add(t2);
```

Now size of hashset would be 2. How to modify this to be of size 1 if the values of the objects is the same ?

example:

```
void eradicateDuplicate(List<Time> list) {

  for (Time t : list) {
     hashSet.add(t);
   } 

}
```

I want this code to eradicate all duplicate time objects with the same value ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen automatically IF you implement the methods `#hashCode` and `#equals` in your Time object.

Comment: And [implement it well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. The second will not be added if it is the same as the first.